# Which should be used after messing up clustered index? Update statistics, Reindex or Reorganize

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

If I have a clustered single column index, e.g `FooId` in SQL Server 2008, 2012 and I know I have messed up the order of the rows to not have sequential order of the `FooId` column anymore, which command/s should be used:

- Update statistics
- Rebuild
- Reorganize

**EDIT**

Scenario
`FooId` is a clustered pk of type sequential uniqueidentifier, but for keeping it simple it this post we use #1 as id values.

`#1 inserted`

`#2 inserted`

`#3 inserted`

---

`#1 selected`

`#1 deleted`

---

`#2 selected`

`#2 deleted`

---

`#2 inserted` (that is reusing the clustered PK of #1)

`#1 inserted` (that is reusing the clustered PK of #1)

---

Isn't this going to break the sequential order? Will it not be stored like this now:

`#3`

`#2`

`#1`

//Daniel

Comment: Please explain more about having "messed up the order of the rows to not have sequential order of the FooId column anymore". Guess you are asking about logical fragmentation but not really clear TBH

Comment: Look at the scenario I complemented with above. I hope it explains more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have misunderstood the way a clustered index works - [by definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the data is logically ordered in the sequence of the clustering key, although it's possible for the clustered index to become physically fragmented as page-splits occur when new data is inserted.

If you want to reduce fragmentation either `REBUILD` or `REORGANIZE` can be appropriate.
The rule of thumb is to do nothing when fragmentation is below 5%, `REORGANIZE` when fragmentation is between 5% and 30%, and `REBUILD` when fragmentation is above 30%.

Index fragmentation is recorded in the DMV [sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). See also [the MSDN page on `REBUILD/REORGANIZE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

It's worth noting that unless you are running SQL Server Enterprise edition, `REBUILD` cannot be performed on-line - meaning that your table will be inaccessible for the duration of the command. `REORGANIZE` is always carried out on-line.

Comment: It's the clustered key I'm talking about. Look at the edited question above. I complemented with a scenario.

Comment: @Daniel - read the links in my answer. The clustered index determines the order the data is stored in the table.